# Ler arquivo linha a linha e coletar strings

Tags: javascript, html

Eu possuo essas duas funções em JavaScript:

```
function verificaExtensao($input) {

    var extPermitidas = ['txt'];
    var extArquivo = $input.value.split('.').pop();

    if(typeof extPermitidas.find(function(ext){ return extArquivo == ext; }) == 'undefined') {
      alert('O arquivo não pode ser validado pois possui extenção não permitida!');
    } else {
      alert('Arquivo validado com sucesso!');
      doc();
    }
}

function doc(){

  document.getElementById('file').onchange = function(){
    var file = this.files[0];

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(progressEvent){
      // Entire file
      console.log(this.result);

      // By lines
      var lines = this.result.split('\n');
      for(var line = 0; line < lines.length; line++){
        console.log(lines[line]);
      }
    };
    reader.readAsText(file);
  };
}
```

A que verifica a extensão funciona normalmente, mas a que seria para mostrar o arquivo no console não chega a mostrar.

Outra dúvida que tenho seria na hora de coletar a string, por exemplo dentro do arquivo eu teria várias linhas e em cada linha teriam várias condições, por exemplo a partir da posição 2 até a 10 devem ser contidos apenas números. Como eu poderia fazer isso?

Meu HTML:

```
<imput type="file" onchange="verificaExtensao(this)" id="file"name="file">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O código não funciona porque você criou um evento `change` dentro da função `doc()` que não faz nada na primeira vez que a função é chamada. E mesmo que funcionasse, daria erro porque você não está passando nada pra função.

Creio que você nem precisa de duas funções, bata usar a função do `onchange` e fazer tudo dentro dela. Se o arquivo for inválido, coloque um `return` após o alert. Daí não precisa usar o atributo `onchange` no `input`.

Veja como fica mais simples:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
   document.getElementById('file').onchange = function(){

    var extPermitidas = ['txt'];
    var extArquivo = this.value.split('.').pop();

    if(typeof extPermitidas.find(function(ext){ return extArquivo == ext; }) == 'undefined') {
      alert('O arquivo não pode ser validado pois possui extenção não permitida!');
      return;
    } else {
      alert('Arquivo validado com sucesso!');
    }

    var file = this.files[0];

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(progressEvent){
      // Entire file
      console.log(this.result);

      // By lines
      var lines = this.result.split('\n');
      for(var line = 0; line < lines.length; line++){
        console.log(lines[line]);
      }
    };
    reader.readAsText(file);
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="file" id="file"name="file">
```

Comment: Funcionou!!! Valeu.

Comment: Veja a linha que deu o erro.

Comment: Na verdade deu o erro: Cannot set property 'onchange' of null na primeira linha. Perdão

Comment: Se o script estiver antes do input file, coloque o código todo dentro desta função: `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){ código aqui });`

Comment: Essa função deve ficar no arquivo JavaScript? Eu sou novo nessa parada

Comment: Atualizei a resposta.

Comment: Boa funcionou!!! se eu quisesse por exemplo fazer condicionais para pegar strings de cada linha, eu deveria colocar essas condições depois do 'for' das lines?

Comment: Acho que dentro do for.

Comment: Blz valeu pela ajuda